# substring a multibyte character safely c#

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to do a substring on a string containing multi byte characters, and I'm not getting the results I expect. I am trying to substring strings like  😂test. The first character is a 4 byte character so calling `ToCharArray` on this string returns:

- 55357 #bytes 1 and 2 of the first character
- 56384 #bytes 3 and 4 of the first character
- 116 #t
- 101 #e
- 115 #s
- 116 #t

So when I call `.Substring(1)` on this string, it returns an invalid string that starts with the third and fourth bytes of the first character, not 'test'. Is there any way to get `.Substring` and other string operations to treat that character as a single unit?

Comment: @ikh: All the required code to reproduce this issue is provided (`.Substring(1)`), isn't it?

Comment: Take a look at this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/70e8cfed-0ec9-4d76-a818-16b6ac6afead/how-to-read-two-bytes-characters-from-string-c?forum=csharpgeneral) maybe can help.

Comment: @Ceilingfish the post in the link (**How to read two bytes characters from string + C#**) :)

Comment: Just to clarify, this character is code point 0x1f602, so it requires one UTF-32 value, 2 UTF-16 values or 4 UTF-8 values. It is called FACE WITH TEARS OF JOY. This is a real and growing problem for .NET programmers. There are nearly 200K of these suckers defined, and only likely to grow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to use [StringInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.stringinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
        var yourstring = "test";
    StringInfo si = new StringInfo(yourstring);
    var substring = si.SubstringByTextElements(1);
```

Comment: Great! never heard about `StringInfo`.

Comment: Note that this method also collapses a character followed by combining characters into one, which might not be what is needed.